# Arduino 10x10 Matrix definition

Tags: matrix, arduino

#### EDIT

**Solved**
Yeah I know I'm stupid it hit me as I was showering :c
I have to use XY[9][9]... should not happen actually :|

So I'm 16 and I'm just trying out stuff... and I'm very sorry for my English.
I've built my own LED matrix(10 by 10) with an Arduino nano and now I want to program a Tetris like game for it.
So i thought it would be easier to use a 2D array then numbers from "0 to 99"

So sure i could use this:

```html
int XY[10][10]
{
  {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
  {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},
  {20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29},
  {30,31,12,33,34,35,36,37,38,39},
  {40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49},
  {50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59},
  {60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69},
  {70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79},
  {80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89},
  {90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99}
};
```

Well X and Y would be inverted but... yeah ^^ :D

But for learning sake i would like to do something like this:

```html
int XY[10][10];
int c = 0; //Count

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      XY[i][j] = c;
      c++;
    }
  }
```

So I'm doing something wrong
cause when I print out:
XY[10][10] I'm getting 0
and for c I get:
100

I know I'm just being stupid right now and it would be nice if someone could
help me

Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah ok, stupid me... I have to use XY[9][9] .. it hit me as i was showering to get rdy .... :c

Answer (score -1):

Try using i<=9 and j<=9...worked for me.

Comment: Yeah i was going to shower this morning and was like... wait omg I'm stupid af ... :c

Answer (score -1):

Of course I have to tell the array that there are 10 elements (10by10) in the array but the first element is still "0" :| got confused there I'm sorry.